# Problems to understand the size of malloc parameter

Tags: c++, malloc

Can anyone explain how does below code work? Cuz I found myself don't know what |malloc(inputNim+1)`and`exit(1)` stands for in below code...

```
buffer = (char*) malloc (inputNum+1);
if (buffer==NULL) exit (1);
```

Comment: `malloc()` is part of the C standard library. It shouldn't be used in C++. The C++ replacement is `new` or `new[]` but actually even this shouldn't be used anymore. The C++ library provides a lot of more convenient [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) (and other things) to get rid of the necessity to use `new` (or `new[]`) in custom code.

Comment: You should tag the question `C`, not `C++`. There is nothing C++-related in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line tries to allocate `inputNum + 1` bytes of memory:

```
buffer = (char*) malloc (inputNum+1);
```

The below line checks if the above allocation succeeded. If `malloc` fails, it returns `nullptr` (`NULL`) and the decision is then to exit the program with return value `1`. A common convention is to exit with `0` on success and something else on failure.

```
if (buffer==NULL) exit (1); // if allocation failed, end program
```

Comment: @Embeddeder FYI: [std::malloc()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc)